# how to create json pojo for this incoming json format

Tags: json

```
[2,"1498134496","StatusNotification",{"connectorId":"1","errorCode":"NoError","info":"NoError","status":"Available","timestamp": "2017-06-22 12:28:16","vendorId":"CPV07","vendorErrorCode":"123ASD"}]
package com.chakra.ev.webservice.jsonschema;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
@Getter
@Setter 
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class StatusNotificationSchema {
   public Integer connectorId;
    public String errorCode;
    public String info;
    public String status;
    public String timestamp;
    public String vendorId;
    public String vendorErrorCode;
}
```

This is the json array im receving,how to do write json schema class for this? The first three doesnt have key and its json array.

Comment: The first 3 parameters needed a name. Other than that it should be straightforward.

Comment: first three doesnt have key and its json array format.I have created pojo for remaining parameters,but dont know to how to call this object

Comment: @user7118237 are you talking about json schema or java pojo class? I tagged jsonschema since you mention that in the question but now I'm not so sure

Comment: if you're talking about Jackson POJO, it has nothing to do with json schema files, which are in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue are the first three array parameters. That is valid JSON though. I think json schema should be something like:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["StatusNotification", ...]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
         "connectionId": {
             //...
         },  //...
      }, // ...
    }
  ]
}
```